# Swift 4 CLLocationManager question: Can I use the location, which is got from CLLocationManager, in ViewDidLoad function?

Tags: swift, swift4

Followed the instructions online, I was able to get my current location using CLLocationManager. And the code structure is as below:

```
var myCurCoordinate:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getLocation()
       print(myCurCoordinate) // HERE I GOT "nil". In my original code, I am not really printing it. Instead, I have another function here that needs to use myCurCoordinate
}

func getLocation() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let loc:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    myCurCoordinate="\(loc.coordinate.latitude),\(loc.coordinate.longitude)"
    print(myCurCoordinate) // HERE print 3 times because of its async
}
```

Can anyone help figure out how can I obtain the location information and be able to print it in the viewDidLoad() ?

Thank you!

Comment: Move the print statement into getLocation.

Comment: it can't be in viewDidLoad because its an asynchronous operation and it needs time to fetch location, instead, you can fetch location in previous viewcontroller and pass into this required viewcontroller to have access in this viewDIdLoad. By the way why are you looking for this requirement?

Comment: @preetam Editted my question. There are some updates in my comments...

Comment: From your comments in the code, ___HERE print 3 times because of its async___ isn't right. You get location updates periodically because you used `startUpdatingLocation()`. If you are certain that you only need location information just once, you can do that by using `requestLocation()` on your locationManager instance.

Comment: you need to call the required function only after location updates. To avoid redundant method calls due to location updates you can put some delay after `stopUpdatingLocation()` or use dispatch_once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't print your location in `viewDidLoad` because it is an asynchronous method you need to wait until it is fetched. You need to stop updating your location using `stopUpdatingLocation()` when you get your location. To do it I prefer to use following.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.last {
        initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude,
                                     longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        print(initialLocation)
        getLocation?(initialLocation)
    }
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

If you are insistent to print it inside `viewDidLoad()` you can do it with closures. 
First, you need to define a closure.

```
var getLocation: ((_ location: CLLocation) -> (Void))?
```

Then in your `viewDidLoad()` method you need to specify what to do when that closure is triggered.

```
 getLocation = { location in
        print(location)
    }
```

Then you need to trigger closure inside `didUpdateLocations` using

```
getLocation?(initialLocation)
```

Comment: But in this method, I still cannot get the location information in the viewDidLoad...

Comment: Recommend you to read following article for better understanding asynchronous programming. https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/managing-async-code-in-swift-d7be44cae89f

Comment: Does the answer useful for you? @KathyLee